# Node.js - Multiple Callbacks on Socket.IO Emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have some issues with my **node.js** application.
Ill send a basic request with the **socket.io-client** to a masterserver. The masterserver checks the ID and if it's valid he outputs valid token.
The problem is when I click on the client the second time the button it will stack the request on the masterserver and outputs the console.log x2.

**Client:**

```
function CheckAuthToken(authtoken, clid, callback){
   var token_state;
   console.log("Checking authtoken: " +authtoken);
   authsocket.emit('auth-token-check', {token: authtoken, clid: clid});
   authsocket.on('auth-token-check-callback', function(authresult){
      if(authresult.clid == clid){
        if(authresult.state ==  "token-valid"){
         token_state = "valid";
            callback(token_state);
      }else{
         token_state = "invalid";
            callback(token_state);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**AuthServer:**

```
socket.on('auth-token-check', function(data){
    mysqlconnection.query('SELECT * FROM `player_token` WHERE `token` = ?', [data.token], function (error, results, fields) {
      if(results.length > 0){
        socket.emit('auth-token-check-callback', {state: 'token-valid',clid: data.clid});
      }else{
        socket.emit('auth-token-check-callback', {state: 'token-invalid',clid: data.clid});
      }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use Promises there.

Comment: what exactly you mean stack, is it not normal to intercept multiple request from same client.

Comment: What I mean by that is when I request for the first time it send's 1 request back which is normal. When I click a second time it sends 2 requests back. A 3rd time 4 requests back. 4th 8 requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Instead of adding all the time persistent Event Listener  ( authsocket.on() )
use authsocket.once.

That fixes my problem.